# Sort the characters of a variable in order of amount of use (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Example:

Enter data to sort: "Hello World"
Sorted: ["l", 3, "o", 2, " ", 1, "H", 1, "W", 1, "d", 1, "e", 1, "r", 1]
In ASCII order
So I want it to go into a table in order of the amount of times it comes up with the amount of times that character comes up.

```
#Like this
uncompressedInput = input("Enter data to compress: ")
# user inputted "abc"
print("Analysing...")
#sorted = str.sort(uncompressedInput)
#print(sorted)
# ["a", 1, "b", 1, "c", 1]
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(uncompressedInput).most_common()
=> [('l', 3), ('o', 2), ('H', 1), ('e', 1), (' ', 1), ('W', 1), ('r', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

If you want the structure exactly like as you said,

> Sorted: ["l", 3, "o", 2, " ", 1, "H", 1, "W", 1, "d", 1, "e", 1, "r",
>   1]

```
>>> l = []
>>> [ l.extend([key,val]) for key,val in collections.Counter(s).most_common() ]
>>> l
=> ['l', 3, 'o', 2, 'H', 1, 'e', 1, ' ', 1, 'W', 1, 'r', 1, 'd', 1]
```

Though, I would not recommend doing that since it will make further computation on this more confusing.

Comment: A `Counter` isn't sorted you need to call `.most_common()`

Comment: Forgot to add that. Thanks @Chris_Rands

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
letters = collections.Counter(uncompressedInput)
print(letters)
```

Comment: `collections.Counter` are not ordered

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
[e for x in sorted(Counter("hello world").items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True) for e in x]
```

Comment: Check `collections.Counter.most_common()`: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Can you say something as to why this works as desired?